# Django instances updates and recall values from history

Tags: django, updates, history

I can track my model instances updates history. I do not know how to proceed further so I can recall instances values by specific date / time.

`class Room` is used to create new Rooms.
`class RoomLog` is used to track changes. If I update Room instance then related RoomLog instance is created. It effect in creating RoomLog instances for every Room instance update.

So, I can change specific instance few times within e.g. a minute or an hour. I can do the same to other instances in the same time or for example I can just NOT change any instance or change some of the other instances and not change all of them.

Although,

I would like to recall the whole table with all latest values of the  instances by specific hour /day or within specific period e.g.

If I choose a time 1:00am then Table is rendered with all instances created at this time. Let's call it Table v0.

Now I start updates and some instances are changed between 1:00am & 2:00am. So, I would like to re-call a table that displays all instances for the time 2:00am and keep in time that some instances were changed but some not. So, some of them have history of changes and some do not have.

and the same for the other hours / days. I hope you get the sense of what I want to achieve.

How to do this ?

These are my two models I use to operate on Room and related RoomLog instances.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Room, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value_original = self.room_value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            response = super(Room, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.value_original != self.room_value:
                room_log = RoomLog()
                room_log.room = self   
                room_log.room_value = self.value_original
                room_log.save()

            return response

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('room_name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.room_name


class RoomLog(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s' % (self.room, self.update_date, self.update_time)
```

---

EDIT

answer below from djq about gt & lte pointed me towards a solution. this is how I have solved it in my views:

```
class AllRoomsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'prostats/roomsdetail.html'
    queryset = Room.objects.all()


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllRoomsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        timenow = tz.now()
        timeperiod= timedelta(hours=1)
        deltastart = timenow - timeperiod
        context['rooms'] = Room.objects.all()
        context['rlog'] = RoomLog.objects.all()
        context['rfiltered'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_time__gt = deltastart)
        context['rfilteredcount'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_time__gt = deltastart).count()
        print timenow
        choosestart = '22:04:30.223113'
        choosend = '22:54:30.223113'
        context['roomfiltertest'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_time__gt = choosestart, update_time__lte = choosend)
        return context
```

Comment: A note on your model - it looks like you have `room_value` defined twice - you might not need it in `RoomLog` as you already are defining the relationship between the two models with `room = models.ForeignKey(Room)`

Comment: I would suggest calling it something else if it has a different function.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but I use room_value in RoomLog so it allows me to track values as well as update time. The name may be misleading but it does same function. I will think about it once I sort out my main problem as per topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to filter your model by time ranges. This might be easier with a `DateTimeField`. Here's an example of how to filter by time range (assuming `DateTimeField`, and a slightly different model structure with the fields `booking_started` and `booking_ended`)

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone as tz

start = tz.now()
time_range = timedelta(hours=2)
end = start - time_range

Room.objects.filter(booking_started__lte=start, booking_ending__gt=end)
```

`lte` and `gt` are shorthands for `less than or equal to` or `greater than`